# Changing multiple texts in html when a button is pressed using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

When I start my HTML up both buttons are there and the < h1> and < p> show up but when I press either button only the < h1> will remain. I've got a portion of my code to change text when a button is pushed, however only < h1> will change, and < p> will disappear. How could I get < p> to change and not disappear?

HTML:

```
   <table cellpadding="10">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button id="button">Change 1</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <h1 id="h1">
                        CS 111
                        <p id="p">
                            Computer Science
                        </p>
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table2 cellpadding="10">
        <tr2>
            <td2>
                <button id="button2">Second Year</button>
            </td2>
        </tr2>
    </table2>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ParagraphChanger.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="SecondYear.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
        /*document.getElementById("change-text").textContent = "Sjklf;ajkflsd";*/
        document.getElementById("h1").textContent = "Anth 200";
        document.getElementById("p").textContent = "Cultural Anthropology";
};

document.getElementById("button2").onclick = function() {
    /*document.getElementById("change-text").textContent = "fdhsakf;jaskdl;fklasd;";*/
    document.getElementById("h1").textContent = "CS 111";
    document.getElementById("p").textContent = "Computer Science";
};
```

Comment: The `<p>` element is wrapped inside the `<h1>` element, so ithe p element is removed when h1.textContent is set to something else.

Comment: Also: paragraph is not allowed in h1, that is invalid HTML, you have a lot of that in just few lines of code or maybe inventing your own html2 ?: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements Permitted content : Phrasing content. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#phrasing_content

Comment: In addition to ikiK's remark (were did you find something like that?) , please avoid using attributes like cellpadding and any other attribute or tag used to modify display. That's what CSS is for. Overall page layout should also not be done using tables, which should be used only to display tabular data (not sure what is the case here, if not relevant discard this last point)

Answer (score 0):

You have your `<p>` inside you `<h1>` and it’s causing you issues when you call the function because your changing `<p>` to null. Put the `</h1>` before `<p>`